# open specified tab kotlin, is possible?

Tags: android, kotlin

i have 2 fragment (notification and approval fragment), but i want this result : my notification click reimbursement and then go to tab reimbursement (in approval fragment), its possible? how to do this?

[image: i want like this after i have clicked reimbursement (example)]

```
my code for intent fragment like this :
private fun navigate(type: String) {
        if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.notificationFragment) {
            when (type) {

                "Approval","CustomAbsence" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
                "Approval","Leafe" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
                "Approval","Reimbursement" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
                "Approval","Overtime" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
                "Approval","Reibursement" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval())
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Just pass a Value in bundle to the Approval Fragment and then set the current tab  as per the value .

Comment: can u give me example code sir?

Comment: my parameter in rest like this : val tab_approval_type:String

Answer (score 1):

You can use viewpager for displaying fragment. When user click in push you need to send type in fragment. Then you can find position by type and set in current position in viewpager

### A simple example##

```
val selectedItem = requireArguments().getInt("positon")

    binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter
    binding.viewPager.currentItem = selectedItem
    binding.tabs.setupWithViewPager(binding.viewPager, false)

    binding.viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object: ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
            selectedPosition = position
        }

        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            selectedItem = position
        }

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        }


    })
```

Comment: how sir? can u give me example of viewpager specified tab? :)

Comment: my parameter in rest like this val notifable_type: Reibursement, my code in approval fragment like this private fun navigate(type: String) {
  if (findNavController().currentDestination?.id == R.id.notificationFragment) {
   when (type) {
    "Approval","Reibursement" -> findNavController().navigate(NotificationFragmentDirections.navigateToApproval()) 
   }
  }




 }

Comment: i am confuse, next  what can i do for this?

Comment: help me sir please

Comment: I will make a simple example in my answer